# How can a US citizen sponsor a Russian citizen for a UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, russian-citizens

I want to sponsor my Russian girlfriend to the U.K. this November for a family wedding. I am a U.S. citizen. What paperwork do I have to show on my part?

Comment: What's your immigration status in the U.K.?

Comment: It has to be asked - have you actually met this Russian girlfriend, or have you only communicated online?

Comment: I am also a tourist visiting the UK. Although my passport has many entries from over the years. Yes I have been seeing my girlfriend from Russia for over a year now. We have  gone on many vacations together in Europe and the Caribbean.

Comment: Entries into the UK that is, in my passport.

Comment: You should edit impotant information into the question rather than put in it a comment.

Comment: They may not accept that you have the capacity for sponsorship if you are a visitor from the US. But otherwise if you are sponsoring, you would submit all of the things the applicant would submit. Given that you are a visitor you should also seriously consider adding the accommodation arrangements. And remember that your sponsorship does not mitigate the need for your gf to qualify in her own right.

Comment: She would need to apply for a visitor visa herself if you're just visiting as a tourist

Comment: Sponsorship isn't nearly as valuable as most people think.  Be prepared for the UK to laugh at the "sponsorship" and eval your girlfriend on her merits alone. Speaking of that, sending her a pile of money to stick in her account to show she has money in the bank totally does not work, search "funds parking" on here.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way if your GF shows that she has enough money for such a short trip, it is around one week. Just a reference from her bank account, showing that she possess and use her account regularly. I think having 2000 pounds for a several month on  bank account would be enough for a 6 month visitor visa.
Alternatively or additionally, a reference from her employer that she has a regular salary. Does not matter how high it is, it should be regular.

Comment: This isn't wrong *per se*, but Her Majesty's Government takes a more nuanced approach to her funding position than much of this answer suggests.  As Harper said above, you should read our QA on [funds parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66104/12065) for a better understanding; essentially, HMG is looking for evidence not just of money but a lifestyle that is stably attached to the applicant's country of residence, to maximise their incentive to return afterwards.  Sponsorship does nothing to enhance this, and can often detract from its appearance.